# ubuntu linux: network config lost after reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I have a linux ubuntu 12.04 machine that was migrated from virtualbox to esxi. I can configure the networking using ifconfig, route add and /etc/resolv.conf and that all works fine. Also I edited the /etc/network/interfaces file with the correct networkconfig.

But still when I reboot the machine the IP address stays what it was. But the netmask turns to 255.255.255.255 and the defalt gateway and the nameservers are lost. When I check th

My /etc/network/interfaces file looks like this:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.11.1.5
    netmask 255.255.254.0
    gateway 10.11.1.254
    dns-search company.be
    dns-nameservers 12.45.1.1 12.45.2.1
```

Any idea what the reason can be?

Answer (score 1):

Is network manager active? Look at /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and check the managed property, it should be set to false:

```
managed=false
```

Check also if resolvconf is installed and working and try removing it.

Comment: Yes, it is disabled (in the file you mentioned). But I even uninstalled network-manager. To no avail.

Comment: It could be the resolvconf program, you can try removing it.